# Provide BigQuery credentials in Apache-Beam pipeline coded in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to read data from bigquery in my beam pipeline using cloud dataflow runner.
I want to provide a credentials to access the project.

I've seen examples in Java but none in Python.

The only possibility I found is to use the : [--service_account_email](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#python_1) argument
But what if I want to give the .json key information in the code itself in all the options like :
google_cloud_options.service_account = '/path/to/credential.json'

```
options = PipelineOptions(flags=argv)
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = 'project_name'
google_cloud_options.job_name = 'job_name'
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://bucket'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://bucket'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    query = open('query.sql', 'r')
    bq_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query.read(), use_standard_sql=True)
    main_table = \
        pipeline \
        | 'ReadAccountViewAll' >> beam.io.Read(bq_source) \
```

Java has a method [getGcpCredential](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/options/GcpOptions.html) but cant find one in Python...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--service_account_email` is the recommended approach as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specifying_a_user-managed_controller_service_account) . Downloading the key and storing it locally or on GCE is not recommended.

Comment: This is just for testing in dev, cause in production I get it through a Jenkinspipeline...

Comment: Are you testing it locally ? If yes then you can use `gcloud init ` and `gcloud auth application-default login` as mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login. This way you don't need to set anything in the application code.

Comment: I'm testing it locally but I want to apply the same test in production though
So I guess to deploy the Dataflow job, it is better to use the --service-account-email approach

Comment: This doesn't work. `--service_account_email` is for using `Dataflow` job, not for getting data in `beam`. I think I should define `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var

Answer (score 1):

For the cases where it is required to use a different path for the json file within the code, you can try the following [python Authentication](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/core/auth.html#explicit-credentials) workarounds:

```
client = Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/keyfile.json')
```

or

```
client = Client(credentials=credentials)
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#loading_credentials_from_a_file) is an example for creating custom credentials from a file:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
```

Comment: That one works for tools like BigQuery or GCS but not with Cloud Dataflow

Comment: That's correct, per the title 'Provide BigQuery credentials', I thought in this possibility, since you could among other things create a new [Beam Source](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-python/#reading-from-a-new-source) to authenticate and read from the BQ client, just in case you want to explore it. But if not, --service_account_email is aimed to use a custom Controller Service Account (not a json), the one that will run the Dataflow job. In this way you won't need to setup the json file, but it requires to have enough permissions to access your BigQuery resources.